# Numbering pages with numbers of different bases (binary, octal, hex, tonal, …)?

Tags: page-numbering, fun

How would one change TeX's pagination numbering system from decimal to one that would number pages in binary, hexadecimal, octal, or any other number system (e.g., the [tonal system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonal_system), with specialized characters for the numerals)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need some command that converts the representation. E.g. with expl3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\renewcommand\thepage{\int_to_bin:n{\value{page}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff    
\begin{document}
blub\newpage blub \newpage blub
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice, it works for binary and hex "out-of-the-box," but how could I implement it using special Unicode characters for specialized numerals?

Comment: @Geremia that is easy just see how footnote counter shows dagger, doubledaager etc, basically just `\ifcase zero \or one \or two \or ....`  replace `two` by whatever character you want to appear for two/